# How to tween entrance/exit with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

With the Meteor library, it handles the "reactive"/"two way binding" interaction styles quite well, if using their (Spacebars) template to generate HTML. However, I'm wanting to do some animated entrances/exits when data changes, and having difficulty getting that to work.

The use case is I have a dashboard gauge widget rendered as an SVG element. When the data driving the gauge updates, I want the needle to animate to its new position, not just snap there.

To have the needle just snap to the new position, I can do something like:

**template.html**

```
<template name="gauge">
  <svg>
    <path id="needle" {{ needleAttrs }} d="..." />
  </svg>
</template>
```

**client.js**

```
Template.gauge.helpers({
  needleAttrs: function() {
    return {
      x: 50,
      y: MyCollection.findOne().needleValue
    };
  }
});
```

This is effectively the same technique used by the [SVG clock example](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/06/a-reactive-svg-demo) that comes with Meteor.

But how can I transition that animation? I was thinking about pushing the new value from the collection into the Session collection such that a separate `animate()` method could find it, and some use of [`Tracker.autorun()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) to make it Reactive, but I haven't been able to get it to trigger properly.

Comment: `Tracker.autorun()` can tell you that `MyCollection` has changed, but it will only monitor at the query level and not at the fine level of individual item properties.  You'll need to preserve the previous value and write an animation function that could be fired off with `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` or similar.

Comment: If you use CSS to set the x and y position, you might be able to use css transitions for this.